# Odd behavior with ostringstream

Tags: c++, ostringstream

I was trying to think of a clever way to concatenate various things into a single string argument for a function without having to use an `ostringstream` explicitly.  I thought of:

```
#define OSS(...) \
  dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream const&>(std::ostringstream() << __VA_ARGS__).str()
```

However, given:

```
void f( string const &s ) {
  cout << s << endl;
}

int main() {
  char const *const s = "hello";

  f( OSS( '{' << s << '}' ) );

  ostringstream oss;
  oss << '{' << s << '}';
  cout << oss.str() << endl;
}
```

it prints when run:

```
123hello}
{hello}
```

where 123 is the ASCII code for `}`.  Why does using the macro get it wrong?

FYI: I'm currently using g++ 4.2.1 on Mac OS X as part of Xcode 3.x.

---

## Solution I'm now using

```
class string_builder {
public:
  template<typename T>
  string_builder& operator,( T const &t ) {
    oss_ << t;
    return *this;
  }

  operator std::string() const {
    return oss_.str();
  }

private:
  std::ostringstream oss_;
};

#define BUILD_STRING(...) (string_builder(), __VA_ARGS__)

using namespace std;

void f( string const &s ) {
  cout << s << endl;
}

int main() {
  char const *const s = "hello";

  f( BUILD_STRING( '{', s, '}' ) );
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to be "clever?"

Comment: Because it's tedious to have to create an ostringstream explicitly.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/algorithm/join.html

Comment: @phooji: that joins a predefined sequence, not an in-line list of "stuff".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A better thread-safe solution without involving the cumbersome macro.**

The original call to function is this:

```
f( OSS( '{' << s << '}' ) );
```

How about if the call is just this:

```
 f(stringbuilder() << '{' << s << '}' );
```

where `stringbuilder` is implemented as:

```
struct stringbuilder
{
   std::ostringstream ss;
   template<typename T>
   stringbuilder & operator << (const T &data)
   {
        ss << data;
        return *this;
   }
   operator string() { return ss.str(); }
};

void f( string const &s ) {
  cout << s << endl;
}
```

Test:

```
int main() {
  char const *const s = "hello";

  f(stringbuilder() << '{' << s << '}' );

}
```

Output:

```
{hello}
```

Online Demo : http://ideone.com/QHFf4

Comment: Yes, this works, but it's not clear to me why this works but using an ostringstream directly doesn't.  Why doesn't this solution have the same problem with the temporary object?

Comment: @Paul: Because now `operator<<` is a member function, which can be invoked on temporary object (also). Even in your code `std::ostringstream() << '{'` invokes member function, and unfortunately there doesn't exist member function which takes `char`, so `{` gets converted into `int` so that the member function can be called on the temporary object. However, when the object is not temporary, an standalone function is invoked, which happens to be a better match.

Comment: Actually, if you change operator<< to operator, (comma) then reintroduce my macro, you get a solution that looks like a traditional function call.  Also, it allows multiple builders to be passed to the same function as separate arguments.

Comment: @Paul: In the macro solution, you cannot replace `<<` with comma. It wouldn't work. However, you can do that in my solution, but that wouldn't be good.

Comment: @Paul: Interesting. Can you post that? Macro and how you use it, both!

Answer (score 5):

`std::ostringstream()` is  temporary which thus can be bound only to const references.  Standalone operator<< (which take non const references as first argument) aren't considered and only the member one are.  The best match in these for a char is converting the char to int.

This problems occurs often with string literals whose address is then displayed.

To solve the problem, the trick is to find a way to transform the temporary in a reference. The member `operator<<`s do that, but only the one for manipulator does it without side effect and only if the manipulator is a noop -- flush could be used.  The members flush and write are also candidates.  So for instance

```
#define OSS(...) \
    dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream const&>(std::ostringstream().flush() << __VA_ARGS__).str()
```

Comment: Using `.flush()` makes it work, but now the compiler warns about returning a reference to a temporary.  Any way to get rid of that?

Comment: @Paul: See my second solution posted as separate solution. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: "_const references_" mutable!

Comment: @curiousguy, fixed. Thanks.  Don't hesitate to edit yourself :-)